# Can you change user agent at webclient?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

There are many that suggested that.

Well, everytime I do something it's always get changed back to nothing.

```
WebClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; EasyBits GO v1.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.3)"
content = WebClient.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/search?q=kucing") 'doesn't work but working at firefox
```

There is a solution for C#
http://codehelp.smartdev.eu/2009/05/08/improve-webclient-by-adding-useragent-and-cookies-to-your-requests/

But c'mon. Do we really have to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to extend the WebClient class to get access to some of the goodies inside.

Just add the example class in your link to your project and use that instead of webclient.  You can remove RefreshUserAgent() as all this does is pick a random user agent each time you call it.